# threejs benchmark and progressive enhancement

Tags: three.js, benchmarking, progressive-enhancement

I am loading a ThreeJS scene on a website and I would like to optimize it depending on the capacity of the graphic card.

Is there a way to quickly benchmark the client computer and have some data that will let me decide how demanding or simple has to be my scene in order to run at a decent FPS ?

I am thinking of a benchmark library that can be easily plugged or a benchmark-as-a-service. And it has to run without the user noticing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/) to monitor performance. it is used in almost all threejs examples and is inluded in the treejs base.
the problem with this is that the framerate is locked to 60fps, so you cant tell how much ms get lost by vsynch

the only thing i found to be reliable is take the render time and increase quality if its under a limit, decrease it if it takes too long

Comment: i was thinking the same but my model does not animate. to be clear it does animate and drop fps only when moving the mouse. this means the render is pretty good at first load but slow at mouse move. does it mean i should enhance after the first mouse move? or trigger an initial animation just for benchmarking purpose ?